# Excel & Word DevExpress

Tags: devexpress

I'm wondering where and how can I download the Excel and Word in DevExpress.
In the office, I can open the project that I'm working on. But if I try to open at home, it says Word and Excel reference can't be located.

Please see attached to see what I'm refering to. Thanks for your help

http://www.mypicx.com/05272009/pic/

=====

Answer:
yes it's installed in my PC. How can I add a new reference?

====

btw this is another error again when I added the reference excel and word:

===========
if you cant open the file you can view the .gif file here:
http://www.tintin.ws/images/gif/pic.gif
http://www.mypicx.com/05272009/mypic/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In add/remove programs change the install and include ".Net Programmability". This will install the Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA's)

Comment: I'm in "change or remove programs" now what should I look in here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Office installed on your home pc. Try deleteing and re-adding the references.

Answer (score 1):

Is Microsoft Office installed on your home computer?